# Why does my SMTP TLS v1.3 connection attempt result in Win32Exception: The Local Security Authority cannot be contacted

Tags: .net, smtpclient, .net-4.8, tls1.3

I have some diagnostic code (.net framework v4.8 and C++/CLI code if you're wondering about the odd syntax) that reports errors via email and I've been trying to ensure it supports TLS 1.3:

```
System::Net::ServicePointManager::SecurityProtocol = System::Net::SecurityProtocolType::Tls13;

System::Net::Mail::SmtpClient^ smtpClient = gcnew System::Net::Mail::SmtpClient(emailServer, port);
smtpClient->UseDefaultCredentials = false;
System::Net::NetworkCredential ^_NetworkCredential = gcnew System::Net::NetworkCredential(loginName, loginPassword);
smtpClient->Credentials = _NetworkCredential;
smtpClient->EnableSsl = true;

smtpClient->Send(mailMessage);
```

When I connect to a gmail SMTP server (and the same for a linux based test server) I get this:

```
Authentication error. Please check that the email certificate and system date / time are correct : System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The Local Security Authority cannot be contacted
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Exception exception)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Boolean renegotiation)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Boolean renegotiation)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Boolean renegotiation)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Boolean renegotiation)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Boolean renegotiation)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.Flush()
   at System.Net.Mail.ReadLinesCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn)
   at System.Net.Mail.EHelloCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, String domain)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Exception exception)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Boolean renegotiation)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Boolean renegotiation)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Boolean renegotiation)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Boolean renegotiation)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Boolean renegotiation)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.Flush()
   at System.Net.Mail.ReadLinesCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn)
   at System.Net.Mail.EHelloCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, String domain)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
```

I had to manually enable TLS 1.3 support on my Win10 machine as per the guide here: https://www.asustor.com/en/knowledge/detail/?id=&group_id=1011

Is it possible I've missed a step or there's something wrong with my Windows machine that would prevent TLS 1.3 SMTP connections?

**Edit**

Just to clarify, on my Windows 10 machine, if I don't make any changes, If I check `System::Net::ServicePointManager::SecurityProtocol` it reports `Ssl3 | Tls` even when Tls 1.1 and Tls 1.2 have been set to enabled and not disabled by default in the registry. It's possible I'm missing a step here but this seems to be the case on both my dev machine and the machine I was trying to deploy my code on.

Comment: There's no TLS 1.3 on Windows 10, no matter what old non-Microsoft articles claim. What you link to isn't a Microsoft guide. The official documentation [clearly says TLS 1.3 is only available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/protocols-in-tls-ssl--schannel-ssp-#tls-protocol-version-support) on Windows 11 and Windows Server 2022. Those old articles were based on the bytes in the *Insider preview* that was eventually released as Windows 11.

Comment: The best solution is to *remove* the attempt to hard-code the TLS version. On Windows 11, Windows Server 2022 and Linux, TLS 1.3 will be used by default. On Windows 10, TLS 1.2 will be used, which is supported by Google Mail.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I'd seen the link you mention but it doesn't explicitly indicate Win10 22H2 (which is what I'm using) doesn't support it at all. You're probably right though as it's not explicitly listed as supporting it.

Comment: ..and fair point on not explicitly setting the protocol version; I was planning on removing that, I just wanted to check TLS 1.3 _would_ work if it were supported on client / server.

Comment: I made a request to Microsoft to clarify the support situation for `Windows 10, version 22H2` to be added to [the docs on TLS support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/protocols-in-tls-ssl--schannel-ssp-#tls-protocol-version-support)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real solution is to *not* use SmtpClient. The [class's own docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=net-7.0#remarks) warn it's obsolete:

> Important

> We don't recommend that you use the SmtpClient class for new development because SmtpClient doesn't support many modern protocols. Use [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) or other libraries instead. For more information, see [SmtpClient shouldn't be used](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0005.md) on GitHub.

The proposed alternative, MailKit is extremely popular with over 80M downloads in NuGet. By default it won't work with anything less than TLS 1.2. From the [FAQ](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/4f9b3363b1c19a7876bd8f6858ac97f2b339ee87/FAQ.md#4-the-server-does-not-support-the-same-set-of-ssltls-protocols-that-the-client-is-configured-to-use):

> MailKit attempts to keep up with the latest security recommendations and so is continuously removing older SSL and TLS protocols that are no longer considered secure from the default configuration. This often means that MailKit's SMTP, POP3 and IMAP clients will fail to connect to servers that are still using older SSL and TLS protocols. Currently, the SSL and TLS protocols that are not supported by default are: SSL v2.0, SSL v3.0, TLS v1.0 and TLS v1.1.

MailKit's [SmtpClient](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MailKit_Net_Smtp_SmtpClient.htm) class has an API similar to .NET's SmtpClient, with a lot of extra features. That means it's almost (but not quite) a drop-in replacement.

```
public static void SendMessages (IList<MimeMessage> messages)
{
    using (var client = new SmtpClient ()) {
        client.Connect ("smtp.myserver.com", 465, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);

        client.Authenticate ("username", "password");

        foreach (var message in messages) {
            client.Send (message);
        }

        client.Disconnect (true);
    }
}
```

It's also possible to cast .NET's MailMessage class to a MailKit `MimeMessage`:

```
public static void SendMessages (IList<MailMessage> messages)
{

...
        foreach (var message in messages) {
            var msg=(MimeMessage)message
            client.Send(msg);
        }
...
}
```

Or even :

```
var msgs=messages.Cast<MimeMessage>();
foreach(var msg in msgs)
{
...
}
```

Comment: Cracking advice - will accept this as the correct answer and will take a look at MailKit to replace our existing solution.

Answer (score 0):

Everything I'd found in my research points to what @Panagiotis indicates in the comments on the original question suggests we should remove the hard-coded value but doing so results in the `System::Net::Mail::SmtpClient` class using TLS 1.0 on my machine.

As much as it goes against Microsoft's advice, the only way I have found to reliably encourage the `System::Net::Mail::SmtpClient` class to use > TLS 1.0 is to set:

```
System::Net::ServicePointManager::SecurityProtocol = System::Net::SecurityProtocolType::Tls13 | System::Net::SecurityProtocolType::Tls12 | System::Net::SecurityProtocolType::Tls11 | System::Net::SecurityProtocolType::Tls;
```

...which does the best it can based on what both the client and server support from my testing (currently TLS 1.2 on my Windows 10 machines).

Comment: Don't use SmtpClient in the first place. The class's [own docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=net-7.0#remarks) have a big warning saying the class is obsolete, no longer updated and suggesting you use MailKit/MimeKit instead. Automatic TLS selection was added in .NET Framework 4.6 but SmtpClient was already marked obsolete by then. It's quite possible it was never updated to use the new algorithms.

Comment: What does the server support? Are you trying to connect to GMail? MailKit supports the current algorithms and authentication methods, including OAuth. It even includes samples that show how to authenticate to GMail using OAuth

Comment: This was some old code so trying to make the most minimal changes in this instance. Makes perfect sense to avoid Smtp Client in the future though.

Comment: Instead of a minimal change, this answer opened a security vulnerability by re-enabling obsolete algorithms. MailKit's SmtpClient has the same methods on purpose, so the only change necessary is to change libraries.

Comment: All *supported* .NET Framework versions, ie 4.6.2 and later, use the best available TLS version. 4.x Versions before 4.6 would use TLS 1.1, not drop to TLS 1.0, unless the *server* required it. You'd have to go all the way back to .NET Framework 3.5 to find TLS 1.0 as the default. All Windows 10 versions [come with 4.6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies#net-framework-46)